# Android app to receive data sent by ESP-01 8266

Tags: android, wifi, esp8266, android-wifi

I want to write an app that receives data sent by ESP-01 8266 and that ESP-01 is connected to the same phone hotspot. What is best way to achieve this?

[image]

Comment: which  data yhou want to receive? Can't you do it using regular connection to your esp-01 8266  IP?

Comment: @VladMatvienko actually the esp-01 sending the data of sensor(3 axis of accelerometer).but i can't understand what do you mean of regular connection.

Comment: using which protocol does it send data?

Comment: @VladMatvienko by default we using http protocol.

Comment: ok, in HTTP there is a client and a server. Which device is a server, and which is a client? Do you request data from that device, or it connects to the phone itself?

Comment: @VladMatvienko As mentioned in picture mobile is acting as receiver and Esp-01 acting as sender and no the app not requesting to device.

Comment: that isn't possible with http I think. There always is a server and a client. Client initializes connection, server accepts connection. Client does request, server sends response

Comment: @VladMatvienko which protocol suitable for this application and that is also faster suggest me please.

Comment: there is no *best protocol*. It's all up to which protocols does your `esp-01` support

Comment: @VladMatvienko esp-01 p2p and Tcp/ip protocol  are supported

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to setup your ESP as a client (ST_MODE). If you don't know how to do it, you should read this [ESP8266 module tutorial first](http://www.geekstips.com/esp8266-01-wifi-module-for-arduino-review-and-tutorial/). Then, on your Android device, you can install an application called Pushbullet. After that, setup an account free on pushbullet website, setup a new notification channel and start sending HTTP requests to that channel from your ESP8266-01. You should receive data sent from ESP8266 as notifications in real time on your smartphone. This is the fastest way :)

Comment: how can one use the cloud if the phone is the AP (nothing mentioned about tethers)

Answer (score 0):

I have used UDP to transmit data to apps from ESP8266.
Using UDP means the data may get lost but the coding requirements are much easier (no hand shakes).

Have a look at this page which goes through all the steps.
[UDP on the ESP01](http://blog.mark-stevens.co.uk/2015/06/udp-on-the-esp01-esp8266-development-board/)

You wil lneed to change the section "UDP Receiver" as that shows code for a Windows UDP receiver and you would need to create an Android UDP receiver.

Answer (score 0):

I have used a simple httprequest from Android phone to ESP8266.
Open/close door application.

Android Java code detail as follow:

```
private void openCloseDoor(final String requestURL) {
reply = "";
new AsyncTask<Object, Void, String>() {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        dialog.setProgressStyle(android.R.style.Widget_ProgressBar_Small);
        dialog.setMessage("Send command to door ...");
        dialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Object... params) {
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(requestURL);
        try {
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

            if (entity != null) {
                InputStream inputstream = entity.getContent();
                BufferedReader bufferedreader =
                        new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputstream));
                StringBuilder stringbuilder = new StringBuilder();

                String currentline = null;
                while ((currentline = bufferedreader.readLine()) != null) {
                    stringbuilder.append(currentline + "\n");
                }
                String result = stringbuilder.toString();
                reply = result;
                inputstream.close();
            }
        } catch (NetworkOnMainThreadException ne) {
            String err = (ne.getMessage() == null) ? "Network" : ne.getMessage();
            Log.e("openDoor", err);
            reply = err;
        } catch (MalformedURLException me) {
            String err = (me.getMessage() == null) ? "Malform" : me.getMessage();
            Log.e("openDoor", err);
            reply = err;
        } catch (ProtocolException pe) {
            String err = (pe.getMessage() == null) ? "Protocol" : pe.getMessage();
            Log.e("openDoor", err);
            reply = err;
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            String err = (ioe.getMessage() == null) ? "IOError" : ioe.getMessage();
            Log.e("openDoor", err);
            reply = err;
        }
        return reply;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        if (dialog.isShowing()) {
            Log.v("openDoor", reply);
            statust.setText(reply);
            statust.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.lightGreen));
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    }
}.execute();
```

}

Call function example:

```
openCloseDoor("http://your domain or ip:port/command");
```

ESP8266 code:

```
#include <WiFi.h>
#include <WiFiClient.h>
#include <WebServer.h>

const int LED_PIN = 16;

IPAddress ip(192, 168, 0, 32);
IPAddress gateway(192, 168, 0, 1);
IPAddress subnet(255, 255, 255, 0);

WebServer server(9999);    

void handleRoot();              
void handleNotFound();
void handleRelay();

void setup(void){

  WiFi.config(ip, gateway, subnet);   
  WiFi.begin("...","...");
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(500);
  }   

  server.on("/", HTTP_GET, handleRoot);                             
  server.on("/<id>", HTTP_GET, handleDoor);     
  server.onNotFound(handleNotFound);  
  server.begin();

  pinMode(LED_PIN, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(LED_PIN, LOW);      
  Serial.begin(115200);
}

void loop(void){

  server.handleClient(); 

}

void handleDoor() {
    digitalWrite(LED_PIN, HIGH);

    // Send door code ....           

    server.send(200,"text/plan","OK");
    delay(500);
    digitalWrite(LED_PIN, LOW);                          
}

void handleRoot() {
  digitalWrite(LED_PIN, HIGH);
  server.send(200, "text/plain", "Ready");   
  digitalWrite(LED_PIN, LOW); 
}

void handleNotFound(){
  server.send(404, "text/plain", "404: Not found"); 
}
```